# SVG Cross-Browser Compatibility Issues

Tags: svg

I am having issues with inconsistent SVG rendering of what seems to be a basic file between browsers. I need to find a way to make this SVG cross-browser, but can't seem to pinpoint the problem. Firefox 23 and Inkscape issues go away if the stop-color statements for the gradients are moved from the CSS to style = style="stop-color:#XXXXXX". Sadly, this is not an option because of the way this file will be used. This file validates on the W3C validator, and seems to only use simple features, but rendering is inconsistent. What is wrong?

I am not allowed to post images yet, so here is a link to an image showing the problem:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/95652985@N07/9754841655/lightbox/

SVG Source is here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11366066/fire.svg

Thanks for help with this baffling problem!

Comment: I've had a lot of problems like this myself and have always just took it as the way it is. Best of luck, I hope there's a better explanation out there.

Comment: Simplify the example as much as possible, ideally so there are only two shapes (one working and one not) and then submit to the browser's bug trackers. Here's a link for Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG

Comment: Hmmmm... the file renders fine for me in FF23 (23.0.1 on Win7).

Comment: Try zooming out to see the effect the OP is talking about.

Comment: I did.  It works fine for me.  I don't know why mine is different.

Answer (score 0):

I think your coordinates x1,y1, etc (for instance

`<linearGradient id="id1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#id0"
 x1="32093.5" y1="4749.35" x2="37189.8" y2="4749.35">`
)

could exceed the user space bounding box, thus got wrapped in Chrome, and clipped in Firefox, etc (also my Ubuntu SVG viewer get the same results as Firefox).

A bit of philosophy: SVG, like HTML, is required to be *tolerant* in rendering, then is common to have different behaviours where the 'simpler' specification is extendend (actually SVG is *far* from simple)

*Edit*: my SVG viewer reports as dimensions: `4252 x 2835 pixels 74,2 kB 34 %`. Even if we multiply 4252 * 3 we are far below the x1,x2 values....